# How to specify which class should extend MappedSuperclass

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, joined-subclass

I have class structure described below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Long revision;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn
public abstract class B extends A {}

@Entity
public class C extends B {}
```

This structure is represented by db structure:
`table B (id, revision); table C (id, dtype);`

But I'd like to have structure like this:
`table B (id); table C (id, dtype, revision);`

Is it possible to define such behavior?

Comment: Some details: I already have a lot of classes that extend A and B.